# Integration testing with Python unittest: how to improve granularity?

Tags: python, integration-testing, pytest, python-unittest, nose

I have a single end-to-end Selenium integration test which consists of several steps with each step setting certain state and passing the data over to the next step.

Test scenario:

```
1. Create item.
2. Assign item to group.
3. Approve item.
...
4. Publish item.
```

The steps are not atomic and depend on each other. The test class extends from `unittest.TestCase` and contains a single `test_xyz()` method which wraps the methods for each step.

Currently, the final report only includes the pass/fail status for the wrapper `test_xyz()` method. I would like to have each step being treated as a 'test step' and have a separate entry in the test report.

It feels wrong to convert all the steps into `test_step1()`, `test_step2()` etc and then enforcing the execution order and data exchange since the steps are not self-contained tests.

Is there a way to mark certain methods as test steps so that they appear as separate entries in the test report?

Basically, all I want is improving the visual reporting so that it is more obvious from the report at which step the entire integration test failed. Is this achievable with `unittest`? What would be the best practice in organizing the code so that it fits into the unittest paradigm?

Not sure `unittest` is the best tool for integration tests, since this is not strictly speaking *unit testing*. Would switching to something like pytest make more sense for integration testing while still allowing 'free' HTML report generation? (I am currently using [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/) to run the test and to generate the HTML report with the corresponding [nose plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-html-reporting).)

Comment: It's kind of hard to say this, since it's my job to review others code written in this, and I really hate it, but... have you considered Robot Framework?

Comment: I had a quick look at the python version of [capybara.py](https://github.com/elliterate/capybara.py) which is being used by dropbox, but found it very poorly documented. Robot seems to be a more established thing, thanks!

Comment: `sub-tests` in unittest give you some control over sharing state within a test function, but it is not really used for integration testing. I'm using it for data driven testing.

Answer (score 11):

### `pytest`

The most flexible option turned out to be switching to [pytest](https://doc.pytest.org/) with [@pytest.mark.incremental](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#incremental-testing-test-steps) and [pytest-html](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/) for HTML report generation.

Also planning to look into the [pytest-selenium plugin](http://pytest-selenium.readthedocs.io) as a possibly cleaner way to organize the selenium fixtures.

The following article proved useful in understanding how to maintain shared state between test steps: http://computableverse.com/blog/pytest-sharing-class-fixtures

### `unittest`

And if you prefer to stick with `unittest`, then for simple use cases like iteration you can use [unittest.subTest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests) as demonstrated in the example below:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import unittest

import requests

HOST='http://httpbin.org'

class TestEndpoints(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_endpoints(self):

        for endpoint in ('/headers',
                         '/ip',
                         '/user-agent',
                         '/response-headers',
                         '/html',
                         ):
            with self.subTest(path=endpoint):

                url = HOST + endpoint
                response = requests.get(url)
                print(url, response.status_code)
                self.assertEqual(response.status_code, requests.codes.ok, msg=f'expected status code {requests.codes.ok}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```